# How do I calculate the attack bonus(es) for Flurry of Blows?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monk

Being fairly new I'm a little lost on the math for this. I read that there is a -2 on attack rolls in the description of "Flurry of Blows". Then in the chart I see FoB has its own attack bonus (+1/+1 at level 3). Then there is the base attack bonus (+2 at level 3). Then the STR bonus. Do all these add up or does the FoB attack bonus *replace* the BAB for this attack?

Sorry if the question sounds stupid. I'm still learning and the books are not quite clear.

Comment: Hi 65BAJA - welcome to rpg.stackexchange.com :). Just to be clear - for which D&D edition are you asking this (D&D 3, D&D 3.5, D&D 4, Pathfinder etc.)?

Comment: Sorry, guess I should have stated that. It's for Pathfinder.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/16652/flurry-of-blows-calculation.

Comment: mxyzplk, I saw that one but was still a little unsure. I think ACE explained it a little better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The formula for a melee attack roll is usually:

> BAB + Str Mod + 1d20

[Flurry of Blows](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk#TOC-Flurry-of-Blows-Ex-) makes two changes to this formula:

> When doing so, he may make one additional attack, taking **a –2 penalty on all of his attack rolls**, as if using the Two-Weapon Fighting feat. These attacks can be any combination of unarmed strikes and attacks with a monk special weapon (he does not need to use two weapons to utilize this ability).

And

> For the purpose of these attacks, the **monk's base attack bonus from his monk class levels is equal to his monk level.**

This makes the attack formula:

> Monk Level + Str Mod - 2 + 1d20

The class table combines Monk Level and the -2 penalty into the column Flurry of Blows Attack Bonus. Giving you the formula:

> Flurry of Blows Attack Bonus + Str Mod + 1d20

Comment: That's what I was wondering. So the BAB for a lvl 1 monk (for FOB) is +1. Then we take the -2 two weapon penalty making the -1 in the chart. Got it.

Comment: Bah, ninja'd by AceCalhoon! and your answer is even better - I'll remove mine... well done.